# how to change the welcomeMenuBox position in SP2013

Tags: 2013, branding

I want to change the welcomeMenuBox position. It need to be alligned with the Logo and Title of the site.
I am using design manager to create the masterpage.
Any suggestion..

Comment: These posts should help you https://www.canviz.com/Canviz-Blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?pID=34 and https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Step-by-Step-Create-a-SharePoint-2013-Composed-Look.aspx